# Combine TuxOnIce and µswsusp?

Tags: linux-kernel, suspend, hibernate

Is it possible to tune [uswsusp](http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Uswsusp)/ [TuxOnIce](http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/TuxOnIce) such that one can write/ read the image for/ from the other suspend system, respectively?

Use case: On my machine TuxOnIce hibernates without problems, but very likely crashes on resume. On the other hand, uswsusp resumes proberly (if it could hibernate), but often enough it failes to hibernate (and if so, it cannot hibernate anymore before rebooting). Combining them might solve the issue ;). (In-kernel swsusp works fine but is achingly slow.)

I expect that to be not possible, but maybe there is a tunable? I use self-compiled kernel.